# Some way to debug WCF method that returns system.io.stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, .net-4.0

How can I debug a method in my WCF service method that returns a system.io.stream? The Microsoft WCF Test Client doesn't let me invoke this method (*the operation is not supported in the wcf test client because it uses system.io.stream*).

How can I test this method?

Thanks.

Comment: Write a console application that calls the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the MSDN document on [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx):

> The following is a list of features not supported by WCF Test Client:
>
> - Types: Stream, Message, XmlElement, XmlAttribute, XmlNode, types that implement the IXmlSerializable interface, including the related XmlSchemaProviderAttribute attribute, and the XDocument and XElement types and the ADO.NET DataTable type.
> - Duplex contract.
> - Transaction.
> - Security: CardSpace , Certificate, and Username/Password.
> - Bindings:
>     WSFederationbinding, any Context bindings and Https binding,
>     WebHttpbinding (Json response message support).

So in order to test this functionality you need to:

1. Generate a proxy class - [See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. Create a Console, WinForm, WPF application that calls the specified method via the proxy class - [See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730144%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

See the [Getting Started Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for WCF for more details.